# Extract row based on a particular value in spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

i am using scala to find a particular word in a line and extract that row, for that the sample that i am using is having data

```
MSH|^~\&|RQ|BIN|SMS|BIN|2019||ORU^R01|120330003918|J|2.2
PID|1|xxxxx|xxxx||TEST|Rooney|19761202|M|MR^^M^MR^MD^11|7|0371 HOES LANE^0371
```

**Below is my code**

```
object WordCount {
    def main(args: Array[String])
    {
        val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxx/xxx")
        val word = textfile.filter(x => x.length >  0).map(_.split('|'))
        val keys = word.map(tuple => (tuple(0),tuple(5),(tuple(6)) ))
        val data =keys.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2+ "," + x._3)
        val srch = data.filter(_.contains("PID")).map(tuple => (tuple(0),tuple(1),(tuple(2)) ))
        val show = srch.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2+ "," + x._3)
        data.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/Sparktest")
    }
}
```

**Result i am getting:**

```
MSH,BIN,20121009151949
PID,TEST^PATIENT,Rooney
```

**Result Expected**

```
PID,TEST^PATIENT,Rooney
```

What is that i am missing. Please help

Comment: So your problem is that you don't want to parse the first line of the file?

Comment: I only want that row to be shown which is containing "PID"

Comment: you are still making the same mistake concerning the escaped pipe first

Comment: @eliasah i tried adding escape also and i found this observation :-
.split('|') and .split("\\|") both are giving the same output !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it not be:

> show.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/Sparktest")

?

Comment: Thanks it was the issue. I don't know how i missed it.
but after correcting it i am getting below result:
P,I,D

Comment: I think you only need to do: val srch = data.filter(_.contains("PID")) then srch.saveAsTextFile

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this code, but it should look something like:

```
val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxx/xxx")
val word = textfile.filter(x => x.length >  0).map(_.split('|'))
val keys = word.map(tuple => (tuple(0),tuple(5),(tuple(6)) ))
val data = keys.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2+ "," + x._3)
val srch = data.filter(_.contains("PID"))
srch.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/Sparktest")
```

Which it could be transformed into something like:

```
val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxx/xxx")
val result = textfile
    .filter(x => x.length >  0)
    .map(_.split('|'))
    .map(array => (array(0),array(5),array(6))
    .map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2+ "," + x._3)
    .filter(_.contains("PID"))
result.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/Sparktest")
```

This way you won't need to give names to each intermediate step (unless if you really need those intermediate steps for something in particular) and would prevent errors like the one you had, which was to save the val `data` instead of `srch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
if i need to search for few more values including PID can i add them like this : .filter(_.contains("PID","MSH")) ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The signature of contains is for a single element only. If you'd like to filter on more than one predicate, you might want to have a look at regular expressions. You could use them like `.filter(_.matches(YOUR_REGEX))`

Comment: Thanks @hasumedic for your help i am really greatfull

Comment: when i am trying to execute your code i am getting this error : value mkString is not a member of (String, String, String)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to understand the conversions. I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Well you are saving wrong data . You should be saving show but not the data. I think you can further refactor the code.

```
case class Header(h1:String,h2:String,h3:String){
   override def toString = h1+","+h2+","+h3
 }
```

Code would look something like

```
object WordCount {
def main(args: Array[String])
{
    val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxx/xxx")
    val word = textfile.filter(x => x.length >  0).map(_.split('|'))
    val keys = word.map(tuple => Header(tuple(0),tuple(5),tuple(6)))
    val search = keys.filter(_.h1.equals("PID")).map(_.toString)
    search.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/Sparktest")
}
}
```

So that suppose in future the case class could be reused

Comment: thanks i already corrected it. i want to know one thing from you suppose i want to extract rows based on two key words example : PID and MSH .
how can i do this ?

Comment: use val search = keys.filter(header => (header.h1.equals("PID") ||(header.h1.equals(""MSH))).

Comment: I tried your code but i am getting this error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of String.

Comment: Edited. Well the reason is i was converting an RDD to String but i should have actually converted RDD[Header] to RDD[String]